# What is the variance of multiple indicator random variables?!

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Consider the following independent random variables $(V_1,V_2,V_3,\ldots,V_n)$ and a random variable $X$ as a function of these other random variables defined as follow on a set $A=(-\infty,x]$:
$$
\
X=f(V_{1},V_{2},V_{3},\cdots,V_{n})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{(-\infty,x]}\left(
V_{i}\right)
\
$$

Are the following assertions true
$$
\
\mathbb{E}\left(  X\right)  =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(  1_{(-\infty
,x]}\left(  V_{i}\right)  \right)  =n\mathbb{P}\left(  A\right)
\
$$
and that the variance is

$$ 
\
var\left(  X\right)  =var\left(  \sum_{i=1}^{n}1_{A}(V_{i})\right)
=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}cov(1_{A}(V_{i}),1_{A}(V_{j}))=n^{2}%
\mathbb{P}\left(  A\right)  \left(  1-\mathbb{P}\left(  A\right)  \right)
\
 $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Please note that $A = (-\infty,x]$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whereas $\mathbb{P}$ is a (probability) measure on the probability space. This means that $\mathbb{P}(A)$ is not even well-defined.

For the first one, note that

$$\mathbb{E} \big( 1_{(-\infty,x]}(V_i) \big) = \int 1_{(-\infty,x]}(V_i(\omega)) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \mathbb{P}(V_i \leq x).$$

Hence,

$$\mathbb{E}X = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(V_i \leq x).$$

If the random variables are identically distributed, then

$$\mathbb{E}X = n \mathbb{P}(V_1 \leq x).$$

A similar calculation yields the variance of $X$; use that

$$\mathbb{E}(1_A(V_i) 1_A(V_j)) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{P}(V_i \leq x) & i=j \\ \mathbb{P}(V_i \leq x) \mathbb{P}(V_j \leq x) & i \neq j. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Saz, but then again if $V_i$ are all identically distributed 
$\mathbb{P}\left(  V_{i}\leq x\right)  \mathbb{P}\left(  V_{j}\leq x\right)
=\left(  \mathbb{P}\left(  V_{i}\leq x\right)  \right)  ^{2}$ even if $i$ is different than $j$

Comment: @rsc05 Yes, that's correct. But note that for $i=j$, we have $\mathbb{P}(V_i \leq x)$ and *not* $\mathbb{P}(V_i \leq x)^2$.